# Calling a Custom Post Type for Related Author Posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Does anyone know how to call a custom post type (CPT) in the `get_related_author_posts()` query?

I am using the function in my functions.php file and then calling it in a CPT template with `<?php echo get_related_author_posts(); ?>` so that links to other content and content types by the same author can appear in the template.

All the research I have done suggests that I should be able to achieve what I want by adding the CPT query `'post_type' => 'webarticle'` to the function.

Seems straightforward, right?

But this is not working for me. Below is my code. Any tips on how to do this or where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post_type' => 'webarticle', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );

    $output = '';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $output .= '<p>' . '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>' . '</p>' ;
    }
    $output .= '';

    return $output;
}
```

**Here is new markup -- still not working -- with the `wp_reset_query()` function added.**

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts ( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );

    wp_reset_query()

    $args = array('post_type' => 'webarticle');
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
        $query->the_post();  
        //code for each post from query//

         $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;

    }
} 

}
```

Comment: Try to add wp_reset_query() in the end of your function. Than you'll should be able to create new query with 'post_type' => 'webarticle' args

Comment: Thank you very much @ValeryStatichny. This looks like a hopeful suggestion. Adding `wp_reset_query()` to the end of my function is simple enough, but now I am having problems with the second half of your recommendation. Would you be able to provide a sample of the new query? I've tried a few different args and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont know how to put formated answer in the comments yet - that's why I put in answers, so please dont blame me if it worthless - it's only suggestion :)

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'webarticle');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
        $query->the_post();  
        //code for each post from query
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @Valery. I've been looking around for a solution and your suggestion is the best so far. But I still can't get it to work. My error logs say that the line of code containing `$args = array('post_type' => 'webarticle');` is producing the error. I pasted the new markup including the `wp_reset_query()` function and the new custom post type query above. I really appreciate your help so far. Does anything else come to mind?

Comment: Yes, the full code, as I would enter it into my functions.php file is above, edited into my original question and under the bold heading "Here is new markup..." The code I use to call it is `<?php echo get_related_author_posts(); ?>`

Comment: I hope thar whole code is not entire in fucntions.php. Thst part of code which depends on output  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
        $query->the_post();  
        //code for each post from query
    }
should be raising on page, where you are usnig query. Sorry, if I didnt clearout the question.

Comment: I tried separating the code so that `if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
        $query->the_post();  
        //code for each post from query` is in the custom post type template, but it still didn't work. Thank you -- very, very, very much for trying to help me. Maybe I don't know enough to make it work.

If anyone else has suggestions I am open to more ideas. Thank you...